# Image carousel onmouseover data-slide-to

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have an image carousel written using HTML and PHP.
This image carousel consist of 2 parts - main carousel (bigImgCarousel) and thumbnails (mCustomScrollbar).

The thumbnail section named "mCustomScrollbar" showing the thumbnails of the images in the carousel. When the user clicks on the thumbnail, the main carousel will slide to the clicked image.

```
<li data-target="#carouselCustom" data-slide-to="<?php echo $thumbnailCnt; ?>" class="<?php if($thumbnailCnt == 0) { echo 'active'; } ?>">
   <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo BANNER_PATH.'assets/landing_banner_images/'.$imageThumb['banner_path']; ?>" width="160px" onmouseover="bannerPreview()" />
</li>
```

How can I go about changing the clicking of thumbnail action to "onmouseover", such that when the user mouseover a particular thumbnail, the main carousel will slide to that image.

The $thumbnailCnt refers to the slide number of the particular image in the carousel.

```
data-slide-to="<?php echo $thumbnailCnt; ?>"
```

```html
<div id='carouselCustom' class='carousel slide' data-ride='carousel'>
  <div class='carousel-outer'>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class='carousel-inner'>
      <?php $bannerCnt=1; foreach($images as $image) { ?>
      <div id="bigImgCarousel" class="<?php if($bannerCnt == 1) { echo 'active'; } ?> item">
        <a href="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo BANNER_PATH.'assets/landing_banner_images/'.$image['banner_path']; ?>" height="585px" data-bgfit="cover" data-bgposition="center center" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat" onmouseover="bannerPreview()" onmouseout="bannerOffPreview()"/>
        </a>
      </div>
      <?php $bannerCnt++; } ?>

      <div id='banner-mouseover-area' style="position: absolute;bottom: 0px; display: none;">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class='carousel-indicators mCustomScrollbar'>
          <?php $thumbnailCnt=0; foreach($images as $imageThumb) { ?>
            <li data-target="#carouselCustom" data-slide-to="<?php echo $thumbnailCnt; ?>" class="<?php if($thumbnailCnt == 0) { echo 'active'; } ?>">
              <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo BANNER_PATH.'assets/landing_banner_images/'.$imageThumb['banner_path']; ?>" width="160px" onmouseover="bannerPreview()" />
            </li>
          <?php $thumbnailCnt++; } ?>
        </ol>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Left and right button to navigate to the next and previous image.

```
<!-- Controls -->
                    <!-- Left -->
                    <div id="leftControl" style="position: absolute; margin-top: -20px; left: 20px;" class="tp-leftarrow tparrows default round" data-target="#carouselCustom" data-slide='prev'>
                        <div class="tp-arr-allwrapper">
                            <div class="tp-arr-iwrapper">
                                <div class="tp-arr-imgholder" style="visibility: inherit; opacity: 1; background-image: url(&quot;undefined&quot;);"></div>
                                <div class="tp-arr-imgholder2"></div>
                                <div class="tp-arr-titleholder"></div>
                                <div class="tp-arr-subtitleholder"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Right -->
                    <div id="rightControl" style="position: absolute; margin-top: -20px; right: 20px;" class="tp-rightarrow tparrows default round" data-target="#carouselCustom" data-slide='next'>
                        <div class="tp-arr-allwrapper">
                            <div class="tp-arr-iwrapper">
                                <div class="tp-arr-imgholder" style="visibility: inherit; opacity: 1; background-image: url(&quot;undefined&quot;);"></div>
                                <div class="tp-arr-imgholder2"></div>
                                <div class="tp-arr-titleholder"></div>
                                <div class="tp-arr-subtitleholder"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's it doing or not doing with what you have now?

Comment: Also lets see your js what you have now on the click version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your data attribute name to something different and change the slides in JavaScript like this:

Your PHP:

```
<li data-target="#carouselCustom" data-change-to="<?php echo $thumbnailCnt; ?>" class="<?php if($thumbnailCnt == 0) { echo 'active'; } ?>">
  <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo BANNER_PATH.'assets/landing_banner_images/'.$imageThumb['banner_path']; ?>" width="160px" onmouseover="bannerPreview()" />
</li>
```

JS:

```
var changeTo;

$('#carouselCustom .carousel-indicators > [data-target="#carouselCustom"]').mouseover(function() {
  changeTo = parseInt($(this).attr('data-change-to'), 10);
  $('#carouselCustom').carousel(changeTo);
});
```

You can also prevent continuous changing slides when you hover over couple of your thumbnails fast enough by changing pointer events CSS property on `slid` and `slide` events:

```
$('#carouselCustom').on('slide.bs.carousel', function() {
  $('#carouselCustom .carousel-indicators > [data-target="#carouselCustom"]').css('pointer-events', 'none')
});

$('#carouselCustom').on('slid.bs.carousel', function() {
  $('#carouselCustom .carousel-indicators > [data-target="#carouselCustom"]').css('pointer-events', 'auto')
});
```

If you want to support touch devices you can use touch events in JavaScript like `touchend`.

Comment: changeTo = parseInt($(this).attr('data-change-to'), 10); is returning NaN

Comment: Did you change your HTML attributes to data-change-to? I tested this solution and it worked.

Comment: Yes, I have changed it to data-change-to

Comment: Thanks makshh, just tested it is working now. However, I realised that after making the changes that you recommended. I couldn't the left and right button that I have to navigate to the next and previous image. This error is show "bootstrap.js:441 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of undefined"

I added in that section of code, please see from the question above.

Comment: I've updated the answer, change `$('[data-target="#carouselCustom"]')` to `$('#carouselCustom .carousel-indicators > [data-target="#carouselCustom"]')`

Comment: It works fine. Also, would like to check that is there a function that I can increase the speed of changing the slide to be faster? For instance, when I mouseover the 1st image and to the 4th image, the big images slide one by one to the next selected one. Can it move faster from the 1st to 2nd instantaneously?

Comment: Hmm strange, Bootstrap doesn't work that way. If you check their example in documentation you will see that when you click to change slide to 3 it slides immidiately to that slide. http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130409/discussion-between-makshh-and-beny-lim).